# How to get story page number in an IDML Document?

Tags: xml, adobe, adobe-indesign, idml

I require extracting the page number of a particular story in IDML Document. However, I'm unable to find any way to do so.There is a page tag in spread_xxx.xml describing pages in a spread. But that has no particular mapping to a story or vice-versa.

Comment: This makes sense, as the story is just a placeholder for your text and not necessary placed into a document. Story can also be spread  across multiple pages.

Comment: But is there any way of finding the page number of text fragment in the story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ExtendScript you can query parents of the placed story paragraph and one of them is the page.

I do not see an easy way to do this in IDML

There is a folder called Spreads with a separate spread for every two pages and with page being child element of the spread.You can also see text frames

Stories have their IDs like Self="u18e". You can see them in the designmap.xml as idPkg:Story.

How the paragraphs are linked to spreads I can not find.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As one said in another forum where you might have asked*  :

IDML isn't a representation of a document but a bunch of instructions about how to construct the document. So a page number can only be accessed at the document interpretation stage i.e. opening the idml file.

*(this question is present in multiple forums at this time)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Since you said that the IDML is just a bunch of instruction about constructing the document. Since the interpretation stage constructs the document putting text content in appropriate page and putting the pages in appropriate order. Won't the IDML document be having these instructions on which page to put the text content? Sorry, I'm missing something obvious I'm new to IDML and InDesign altogether.